# How to create an Auto-ID inside a firestore without collection?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

```
const autoID= this.db.collection('dynamic id creation').doc().id;
```

I have managed to create the auto generate id inside firestore. but i do not want using collection.

when, I am removing(collection('dynamic id creation') this line getting error

> "message": "Function Firestore.doc() requires 1 argument, but was called with 0 arguments.

Can some one please suggest where i am doing mistake. or how create auto generated id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generate an auto-ID without specifying a collection, the API simply doesn't allow for that.

But it doesn't matter whether the collection exists or not, as the ID is in no way related to the collection you specify.

So this is totally fine:

```
this.db.collection('this is not a collection, but just here to make the call work').doc().id;
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank van puffelen for clarification !